# Control specific elements in a shared element animation

Tags: android, activity-transition

In my app I have a shared element that looks something like this

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/hero_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

In my activity I mark the `image` as the shared element and thus the image transitions to the next activity. However, I want to fade out the `title` before the image is transitioning. It looks like I should be able to get this working by using `setSharedElementExitTransition()` and setting the `title` as a target, but whatever I try, that animation appears not to work and the transitioning image is drawn over the snapshotted `title`.

I've read through https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2014/12/08/what-are-all-these-dang-transitions/ by George Mount and looked through his excellent answers here on SO, but I just need a little bit more help :)

Comment: A few questions: (1) What type of shared element transition are you using? You mention that you are using a shared element exit transition, but what type of exit transition are you setting? What type of enter shared element transition are you using as well? (2) Which views are the shared elements you are trying to transition across activities? Is there only one shared element (the image) or is the title a shared element as well?

Comment: (1) I'm using Activity transitions with `ChangeBounds` as the shared element enter transition. I've set `Fade` on the exit transition with the title as a target. I've also tried fading in the shared element in the enter transition to no avail. (2) I only need to transition the image in this example.

Comment: What effect are you seeing? The exit transition should be picking up your title fade. Are you setting the visibility to INVISIBLE after the startActivity?

Comment: @GeorgeMount I was missing that, and I had a window exit transition set as well.

Comment: Only thing I can't figure out now is how to make it work when I set a window exit transition to `Explode`, the shared element exit transition seems to be skipped in that case.

Comment: Oh, the usual gotcha. Should have used `setReturnTransition()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to get the basics working, assuming `setTransitionName("text")` is called on the title view

1. Set the proper shared element exit animation in Activity A:

   ```
   getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(new TransitionSet().
               addTransition(new Fade().addTarget("text"));
   ```
2. After `startActivity()` is called, change the visibility of the title text view using `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. This is required to make the fade work.

Setting the view to `INVISIBLE` was the essential step that I was missing, and I also had a window *exit* animation set. However, I should have set a window *return* animation using `Window.setReturnTransition()`.